# Problem about Extending root space with gparted (and bootloader)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, gparted, bootloader

I have both windows and ubuntu installed in my computer, and I wants to extend my ubuntu root space, but I have some complicated problems, here is the image:
[image: My boot location]

as you can see, my boot is installed with my windows boot. 
On the other hand, my ubuntu is installed in another disk, and is shown here:

[image: my ubuntu location]

I'm a new to linux, Since it is not LVM, I think I should resize my root by Gparted liveCD, deleting dev/sdb3 and resize root to include unallocated space, but:

1) I don't know whether deleting /dev/sdb3/ with label "boot, esp" will cause any problem?

2) Since bootloader is in other disk, will I lose bootloader?

3) I have checked the existing post in askubuntu, and in here
[image: Why I'm seeing a lock besides the partition I'm trying to modify with gparted?] it said that resizing disk space in gparted is enough and just reboot, but in some other post, e.g  [image: Extend root partition with unallocated space on the left], it is required to rebuild bootloader by myself, which one is correct??

Comment: You can't expand your root partition while you're on it safely unless you're using LVM, and you don't appear to be doing that here.  Boot to a LiveUSB and then resize.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks for your comment, I know I have to boot to liveCD to resize, but I don't know whether it is too complex, my bootloader is in different disk and some post mention bootloader would lose after that [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938910/how-to-resize-root-to-increase-home-partition-size-in-ubuntu-16-04-with-gparted), and some others just say resize and apply[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/why-im-seeing-a-lock-besides-the-partition-im-trying-to-modify-with-gparted).